# Text overlay on images in an column-count block

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add text over images in a column-count block. The goal is to have a couple of images in the div box set to column-count: 2 and have some text in div box over the image. I'm using the column-count to have images with different height nicely under each other without having whit spaces between them.

First I just added the images and the text in divs into the column-count div. I had to learn that if I try to add the text over the images with position relative and absolute that the text aligns to the column div and not to it's direct parent the image. Today I thought of putting the images into the background. That seams to be the right way, but one part of the image is in the first column row and the other in the second row.

Here is my code so far:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.cc{
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count:    2;
  column-count:         2;
}
.cc-block{
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size:     cover;
}
.block_1{
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/650x450/ff0000);
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}
.block_2{
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/650x250/ffff00);
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
.block_3{  
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/650x300/80ff00);
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.block_4{
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/650x450/00ffff);
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}
.block_5{
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/650x550/4000ff);
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;
}
.block_6{
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/650x150/ff00ff);
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cc">
 <div class="cc-block block_1">
  <div>
   <h2>Some Heading</h2>
   <p>Some Paragraph</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="cc-block block_2">
  <div>
   <h2>Some Heading</h2>
   <p>Some Paragraph</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="cc-block block_3">
  <div>
   <h2>Some Heading</h2>
   <p>Some Paragraph</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="cc-block block_4">
  <div>
   <h2>Some Heading</h2>
   <p>Some Paragraph</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="cc-block block_5">
  <div>
   <h2>Some Heading</h2>
   <p>Some Paragraph</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="cc-block block_6">
  <div>
   <h2>Some Heading</h2>
   <p>Some Paragraph</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the fourth image is split. It's clear that this is caused by the column-count, but is there a way to achieve this without splitting the background images. Or is there even a neater way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see the problem. Which is the fourth image? The light blue one? How is it split?

Comment: It's block_4 the light blue one. @exside solutions fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add `break-inside: avoid-column;` to the `.cc-block` class:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.cc{
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count:    2;
  column-count:         2;
}
.cc-block{
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size:     cover;
  break-inside:        avoid-column;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
}
.block_1{
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/650x450/ff0000);
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}
.block_2{
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/650x250/ffff00);
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
.block_3{  
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/650x300/80ff00);
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.block_4{
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/650x450/00ffff);
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}
.block_5{
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/650x550/4000ff);
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;
}
.block_6{
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/650x150/ff00ff);
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cc">
 <div class="cc-block block_1">
  <div>
   <h2>Some Heading</h2>
   <p>Some Paragraph</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="cc-block block_2">
  <div>
   <h2>Some Heading</h2>
   <p>Some Paragraph</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="cc-block block_3">
  <div>
   <h2>Some Heading</h2>
   <p>Some Paragraph</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="cc-block block_4">
  <div>
   <h2>Some Heading</h2>
   <p>Some Paragraph</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="cc-block block_5">
  <div>
   <h2>Some Heading</h2>
   <p>Some Paragraph</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="cc-block block_6">
  <div>
   <h2>Some Heading</h2>
   <p>Some Paragraph</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works like a charm. Didn't think of checking for something like that. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Do you have an idea how I can get Safari to display it like FF and Chrome do? Safari adds block_4 into the first column row, FF and Chrome adds it into the second column as expected.